# Different RF predictions when pasting code from different sources

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

I'm playing around with the German Credit dataset from the "caret" package.

First, I build a very simple model:

```
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
library(pmml)
data(GermanCredit)

GermanCredit <- GermanCredit[, -nearZeroVar(GermanCredit)]
GermanCredit$CheckingAccountStatus.lt.0 <- NULL
GermanCredit$SavingsAccountBonds.lt.100 <- NULL
GermanCredit$EmploymentDuration.lt.1 <- NULL
GermanCredit$EmploymentDuration.Unemployed <- NULL
GermanCredit$Personal.Male.Married.Widowed <- NULL
GermanCredit$Property.Unknown <- NULL
GermanCredit$Housing.ForFree <- NULL

set.seed(100)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(GermanCredit$Class, p = .8)[[1]]
GermanCreditTrain <- GermanCredit[ inTrain, ]
GermanCreditTest  <- GermanCredit[-inTrain, ]

set.seed(1056)
credit.rf <- randomForest(Class~., data = GermanCreditTrain, ntree = 500)
```

Now, if I predict the outcome Class on the test set, and do this several times, and then compare the results:

```
credit.pred1 <- predict(credit.rf, GermanCreditTest)
credit.pred2 <- predict(credit.rf, GermanCreditTest)
credit.pred3 <- predict(credit.rf, GermanCreditTest)

all.equal(credit.pred1, credit.pred2)
all.equal(credit.pred2, credit.pred3)
all.equal(credit.pred1, credit.pred3)
```

I get the same predictions for all 3 passes. Now, I'm doing this by manually typing the code in the RStudio interpreter. But, If I copy-paste the code from my text editor (which I've posted here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/32b3c8194362d2e10527), I get an error message saying that there are 3 string differences in the second and third comparison!

How is this possible?

Comment: You probably made a typo in your text editor.

Comment: Nope, compared them with WinMerge several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using caret's train function:

```
credit.rf <- train(Class~., data = GermanCreditTrain, method="rf")
```

instead of

```
credit.rf <- randomForest(Class~., data = GermanCreditTrain, ntree = 500)
```

I was able to reproduce the issue and not sure what is causing it.  However, the above seems to work when pasted:

```
credit.rf <- train(Class~., data = GermanCreditTrain, method="rf")
> 
> credit.pred1 <- predict(credit.rf, GermanCreditTest)
> credit.pred2 <- predict(credit.rf, GermanCreditTest)
> credit.pred3 <- predict(credit.rf, GermanCreditTest)
> 
> all.equal(credit.pred1, credit.pred2)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(credit.pred2, credit.pred3)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(credit.pred1, credit.pred3)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Unbelievable, that does the trick! Do you have any idea what could be causing the issue? (Or how I could get to the bottom of it?)